# macro to move data from one column to another, by detecting space character in a word of the column

Tags: vba, excel

I converted some pdf files to xlsx format while converting, the data in the pdf files is dispersed in xlsx format, so I wrote a macro to adjust the data.

now the issue is column G has data of food items like  "1 Cream", "7 Cakes","3 Sugars"
I have noticed there is a space character in between the data like this.

also there is a data like some ones Address like "343 Wilson Avenue", "232 The Broadway"

I want to move all the data of food items to H column and want to keep address in the G column.

I have noticed there is always a space on the second character for food items

the code I am using is

```
Sub Price_Adjust()
Dim J As Range, L As Range, G As Range, K As Range, r As Range
Set J = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("J:J"))
Set L = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("L:L"))
Set G = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("G:G"))
Set K = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("K:K"))
For Each r In J
    If Left(r.Text, 1) = "$" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

For Each r In J
    If Left(r.Text, 1) = "(" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r


For Each r In L
    If Left(r.Text, 1) = "(" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, -1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

For Each r In L
    If Left(r.Text, 1) = "$" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, -1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

 For Each r In G
    If Left(r.Text, 1) = "D" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

For Each r In G
    If Left(r.Text, 1) = "H" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

 For Each r In G
    If Left(r.Text, 1) = "T" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

For Each r In G
    If Left(r.Text, 1) = "C" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

For Each r In G
    If Left(r.Text, 1) = "1" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

For Each r In K
    If Left(r.Text, 1) = "P" Then
        r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
        r.Clear
    End If
Next r

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how can I detect food items and address separately by space in the second character of G column

Comment: two tips. 1) **EDIT** your original post and put the question in there, right at the top, and 2) make your variable names more meaningful. It's a little more typing, but you'll appreciate it when you come back to maintain the code in 6 months.

Comment: @mb1987, string parsing is very difficult.  That's why commercial software to do what you're asking is very expensive.  You can use the `MID` function to see if the second character is a space, but that won't work very well as some addresses will have only 1 digit at the beginning as well.

Comment: Geez, @Mr.Mascaro, I just said that in my answer, Which I was typing while you posted this...

Comment: @FreeMan, I agree 100%.  I just didn't want to answer.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro there was a ;) implied at the end there, just in case you didn't catch it.

Comment: @FreeMan, totally got it.

Comment: `there is always a space on the second character for food items`  What about an address like `6 Pear St`?

Comment: I think you are going to have to check if the second word is the name of a fruit.  If it is, you'll need to check that there is not something following that indicates it is an address (e.g. Ave, Rd, Lane, LN, etc).  And even then you can still have errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to determine that the 2nd character of a string is a `space`, use this:

```
Dim TheString as String
TheString = "6 ducks"
If Mid(TheString, 2, 1) = " " Then
  MsgBox "There's a space in position 2 of the string"
End If
```

For your particular use, be careful, you may run across addresses like `4 Wicker Drive`, and end up with incorrect data sorting.

**UPDATE** based on comment:

Put this code in a loop of some sort to run through your range of used cells in column `G`

```
If IsNumber(Left(MySheet.Range("G" & SomeRow), 1) Then
  MySheet.Range("H" & SomeRow) = MySheet.Range("G" & SomeRow)
  MySheet.Range("G" & SomeRow) = ""
End If
```

Comment: I know that, I have filtered the address data  in dispersed column that are having 3 numbers in it front,  do you know a way to move all data from H to G column that has 3 numbers in the front of a string?

Comment: Glad that helped. As many of the comments have noted, using a simple algorithm like this is fraught with dangers, but if it's a one-timer, or you're aware of the potential errors, and someone will be reviewing, this will work for you.